# {{#if currentUser}} too slow

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have created an Admin area on my website, which is protected by a login, that is powered by the account-package.
My Admin Template currently looks like this:

```
<template name = "Admin">
{{#if currentUser}}
    {{> SideNav}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template = getCurrent}}
{{else}}
    {{> Login}}
{{/if}}
</template>
```

It works, but when i change the website, it always shows the login page for a second, before it changes to the dynamic template. It is short, but you can notice it and it doenst look very nice. So how should i go about this? I am not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bringing your logging-in logic on the view might be an easy way to do, but as you can see it, it is not worth.

The logging-in related tests must be done asap in your application. You should do it in the router, as it will allow you to efficiently manage the accesses and start subscriptions before the view start rendering (this last point depends on your package and yout way of managing the renders though).

In addition, several packages provides very relevant tools to improve your app perfs and rendering in this kind of situation.

Here are some of them :

- meteorhacks:fastRender
- meteorhacks:subscription-manager
- kadira:flow-router (rather than Iron:router, which is way more random in rerunning the route and renders.)

Here is some example of how you would handle it with Flow Router.
The following example architecture is built according to The Meteor Chef model.
In this example, I assume you use alaning:roles package and code according to last version of Ecmascript.

**/both/routes/__triggers.js**

```
// Let's declare some namespace for our routing triggers
Triggers = {};
Triggers.mustBe = {};
Triggers.mustNotBe = {};

// Here, we check for the state of the client
Triggers.mustBe.loggedIn = ( ) => {
  if (!(Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.userId()))
  // If he is not logged in or logging in, we handle the redirection
  {
    FlowRoute = FlowRouter.current();
    if (FlowRoute.route.name != "home")
      Session.set("redirectAfterLogin", FlowRoute.path);
    FlowRouter.go('/splash');
  }
};

Triggers.mustBe.admin = ( ) => {
  // Same here. If the user is not an admin, we should redirect him somewhere or prevent the routing to be executed
  if (!Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin']))
    FlowRouter.go(FlowRouter.current().path);
};

// Just an example of what if would looks like if we wanted to be sure the client is not connected (for accessing the login screen for example)
Triggers.mustNotBe.loggedIn = ( ) => {
  if (Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.userId())
    FlowRouter.go('/');
};
```

**/both/routes/_configuration.js**

```
// We set the rendering root to the 'body' tag. Check for the doc links I give below
if (Meteor.isClient) Meteor.startup(function() { BlazeLayout.setRoot('body'); });

exposed_Routes = FlowRouter.group({
  name: "exposed",
  triggersEnter: []
});

loggedIn_Routes = FlowRouter.group({
  name: "loggedIn",
  triggersEnter: [
    Triggers.mustBe.loggedIn
  ]
});

// You might see that we declare the admin routes group from the logged_in group. Doing so, we will execute all the logged_in triggers before executing the one we define here. It will allow us to check if the user is connected before checking he is an admin
admin_Routes = loggedIn_Routes.group({
  name: "admin",
  triggersEnter: [
    Triggers.mustBe.admin
  ]
});
```

**/both/routes/admin.js**

```
admin_Routes.route('/admin/reports', {
  name: "reports",
  action: function (params, queryParams) {
    // We use kadira:BlazeLayout package to manage the rendering
    BlazeLayout.render('adminLayout', { main: "someTemplate", menu: "SideNav" });
    // Any other logic you would execute each time you create this route.
  }
});
```

**/client/templates/layouts/admin.html**

```
<template name="adminLayout">
  {{> Template.dynamic template=menu }}
  {{> Template.dynamic template=main }}
</template>
```

**[BlazeLayout](https://github.com/kadirahq/blaze-layout) & [FlowRouter](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router) docs (by Kadira)**

Comment: Logging or Logging In?

Comment: For the User of Roles.userIsInRole i have to use this package right? https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

Comment: I am getting a Refernce Error for admin_routes, when i use it in admin.js. Is there something missing in the code or did i do a mistake?

Comment: I did a copy-paste from my own "template" app architecture that i use each time I start a new app, though I deleted some parts. Could you give me your error plz ?

Comment: It has to do with your load order.

In Meteor, files are loaded in a very specific way.

here are some very good explanation : [https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/organizing-your-meteor-project/](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/organizing-your-meteor-project/#tmc-load-order)

You have to keep the _ as the first (and sometimes second, too) characters of your file name to manipulate the load order.

That's for the same reason we have to set the BlazeLayout root it this file, in a `startup` in a `isClient`, to deal with the load order, the scope and the execution time in a single time.

Comment: Quoted from TMC :

"It’s also important to pay attention to the file name. Notice that the file is called _modules.js. This isn’t a typo. This ensures that this file gets loaded first before all of the other files. Why? Because this contains the definition of the Modules variable that we’ll need access to in other files (the _ character puts the file first alphabetically and avoids the need for adding a /lib directory). This ensures that it’s available when we need it."

Comment: OKe ive got it now. Meteor doesnt like me naming the files with the first letter in uppercase. renaming the 3 files, so its all lowercase fixed the issue. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need `{{loggingIn}}` helper which is reactive and is `true` while login method is currently in progress.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_loggingin

```
<template name = "Admin">
    {{#if loggingIn}}
        Loading...
    {{else}}
        {{#if currentUser}}
            {{> SideNav}}
            {{> Template.dynamic template = getCurrent}}
        {{else}}
            {{> Login}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```